# In python, is there any advantage to use two lists instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have two ways to find the youngest member: using a dictionary and using two lists.
for example:

```
ages_dic = {'Green':14, 'Green':34, 'Hesper':11}
```

vs.

```
names = ['Green', 'Green', 'Hesper']
ages = [14, 34, 11]
```

I know the advantages of using a dictionary, just wondering if there is a time that we want to use the two lists method instead of using a dictionary?

Comment: Both data structures are suboptimal if your goal is to find the smallest/largest age.

Comment: The dictionary won't be able to store two values with the same key, but the list-based solution will. In general, it's a pretty bad idea though.

Comment: Are the duplicate keys on purpose? If yes the dict not only has no advantage, it is completely unsuitable to reliably solve the task.